# How to use jsp:useBean action tage to process a form?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to handle a simple JSP form, that accepts your first and last name, and then prints:

```
Your first name: entered_first_name  
Your last name: entered_last_name
```

using jsp:useBean action tags, so far with no luck...

Let me first show what I have written so far, and then I'll explain the problem.
This is how the UserData class looks like:

```
package pack;

public class UserData {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

This is how the first form (**index.jsp**) looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <jsp:useBean id="userinfo" class="pack.UserData" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="userinfo"/>
    <body>
        <form action="MyServlet" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the relevant part from **MyServlet.java**:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("another.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

and this is **another.jsp**:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <jsp:useBean id="userinfo" class="pack.UserData"></jsp:useBean>
    <body>
    Your first name: <%=userinfo.getFirstName() %><br>
    Your last name: <%=userinfo.getLastName() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run `index.jsp`, enter my first and last name, and hit "Submit", I get:

```
Your first name: null  
Your last name: null
```

Which is obviously bad.
First of all, and most importantly: what am I doing wrong? why aren't the setters invoked?
Second, as you might noticed, MyServlet.java doesn't do much. it only redirects to another.jsp, so do I really need it? is there a faster, more elegant way for redirecting from one jsp to another in cases where there is no much work to do between redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put a UserData bean in a request **attribute** in your servlet before forwarding :

```
UserData userinfo;
userinfo.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName");
userinfo.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName");
request.addAttribute("userinfo", userinfo);
request.getRequestDispatcher("another.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

If you want things to happen automatically, you will have to use a framework such as Struts2, Spring MVC, or ...

Comment: no tomcat is as server . framework in the sense something like spring , struts . which implements java features and helps you in building mvc apps

Comment: @so.very.tired : No, Tomcat is a servlet container. Examples of MVC framework are [Struts](http://struts.apache.org) or [Spring (MVC part)](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple form example to understand `Bean` properties

**index.html**

```
<form action="welcome.jsp">
Enter Name:<input type="text" name="firstName"/>
<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="pack.UserData" />
<jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="*" />    
Welcome, <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="firstName" />
```

**UserData.java**

```
public class UserData {
private String firstName;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        System.out.print("the values are"+firstName);
    }
}
```

You will get the values entered in the html page .